# Is it possible to view the contents of /data/app on a wearable?

Tags: wear-os

I'd like to check the contents of /data/app on my wearable device, however if I use

```
adb shell
cd /data/app
ls
```

Then I get "opendir failed, Permission denied". 
Is there a way of being able to perform the su command on a wear as there is on a handheld or another way of browsing the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way is to root the device. There are a bunch of "how to" guides out there that explains what you need to do step by step.